# In “run out of food by night” is “by night” part of the “out of food” PP?

Tags: syntax

In the sentence:

> run out of food by night.

“out of food” will be one single PP.

“by night” will also be a PP, but will it be part of VP or will it be inside the "out of food" PP?

Comment: It depends on your framework

Comment: What if the sentence is "I will run out of food by night.".  What will be the tree diagram for this?

Comment: I understand your question. The answer depends on your framework. Personally I put two PPs under VP. But this will not work under the Minimalist Progam for example. So you should specify which framework you're using.

Comment: I'd say that the VP consists of four constituents: “run + out” + “of food" + by night”,

Comment: I am using Phase structure grammar

Comment: "By night" can mean "before or during night" or "during night": see [sense 3a and 3b here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by).

Answer (score 0):

I read it as attaching to the verb.
There are other possible expressions:
*It ran dry by nightfall.*
*It came loose in an instant.*

In those examples, there is only one PP, and it modifies the time of the action of the verb.

Inserting another PP doesn't change the attachment of the time PP to the verb.
*It came off the wall in an instant.*

Comment: so with VP as main. V(rain) -> PP(out of food) PP(by night). V is taking 2 PP as argument in this